# Edge browser shows each tab as a new window in Alt + Tab

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge, alt-tab

When I switch between tasks in <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>, the Edge browser shows all tabs as a separate tasks while other web browsers do not.
Can I change this Edge behavior like other web browsers?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

1. Open ***Windows Settings*** → ***System*** → ***Multitasking***
2. In Multitasking settings, scroll down to ***Pressing Alt+Tab shows***
3. In the menu, select ***Open Windows Only.***

[image]

Like so.

Answer (score 9):

This setting in Windows 11 is slightly different. Here are the steps for Windows 11:

1. Open Settings from the Start Menu
2. Click on System from the left-hand menu
3. Click on Multitasking from the list of settings
4. Under “Show tabs from apps when snapping or pressing Alt+Tab“, select Don’t show tabs.
   [image: Select Don’t show tabs when using Alt Tab]

You can also do the same using Registry Editor, Group Policy Editor and Command line. All these additional steps are discussed in [this article](https://www.itechtics.com/disable-edge-tabs-alt-tab/).

Comment: Stupid dev.'s..... "Show tabs from apps" has a very different meaning..... What they mean is, "Show tabs **from within** apps", or something along those lines.....